# Angular2 RC4 Router: Get the RouteConfigs "data"-Property from Router-Events Subscription in a Service

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

With the new RC4-Router (3.0.0-beta.2) from Angular2, I have the following Route-Setup:

```
export const Routes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: 'account',
        pathMatch: 'prefix',
        canActivate: [
            AppAuthGuard
        ],
        children: [
            {
                path: 'create',
                component: AccountRegistration,
                data: {
                    'title': 'Create an Account'
                }
            },
            {
                path: 'login',
                component: AccountLogin,
                data: {
                    'title': 'Log into your Account'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

It is possible to open the routes. But I have a global Service, which should set the title in the AppComponent from the "title"-property of the routes "data"-property. So I'm subscribing the router.events-Observable:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(value => {

    if (value instanceof NavigationEnd) {

       console.log(this.router.routerState.snapshot.root.data['title']);
    }
}
```

But it's just not possible to get the title. Is that even possible and am I supposed to be able to get route-informations like that? Does anybody have an example for me?

Comment: Cross-ref https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9822

Answer (score 1):

You can subscribe to `data` directly like

```
class HeroDetailComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
      .data
      .subscribe(v => console.log(v));
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: This works only for routed-components, not even directives. But I need to get the current active routes data in a service (also for future features). We are currently working on a big complex SPA, so it would be a really good thing, if it would be possible to describe the routes in a central place.

Comment: Might be possible. I didn't dive too deep into the new router yet.